# Несколько элементов в SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

Возникла проблема с отображением фишек на поле при нажатии на определенное поле. Что я имею ввиду - у меня есть игровое поле, и есть функция которая позволяет по нажатию на левую клавишу мыши размещать фишки на поле, но когда я нажимаю на другую клетку у меня не сохраняется предыдущая позиция фишки, и она перерисовывается в новой клетке. Например фишка была в позиции (0,2), а стала в (3,4), хотя мне нужно, чтобы было две фишки в позиции (0,2) и (3,4). Я пытался создавать массив фишек, чтобы каждый раз отрисовывать новую фишку, но ничего не получилось. Может кто-нибудь подсказать как мне отрисовывать несколько фишек на поле? Заранее благодарю.

```
Texture white;
    white.loadFromFile("images/white.png");
    Sprite White(white);
    Sprite White1(white);
    Sprite White2(white);
    Sprite White3(white);
    Sprite White4(white);
    Sprite White5(white);
    Sprite White6(white);
    Sprite White7(white);
    Sprite White8(white);
    Sprite White9(white);
    Sprite White10(white);
    Sprite White11(white);
    Sprite Whites[12] = { White, White1, White2, White3, White4, White5, White6, White7, White8, White9, White10, White11 };


    Texture texture;
    texture.loadFromFile("images/desk.png");
    Sprite board(texture);

    int w = 64;
    int i = 0;
    int dx;
    int dy;

    while (app.isOpen())
    {

        Event mouseEvent;
        app.clear(Color::White);
        while (app.pollEvent(mouseEvent))
        {
            if (mouseEvent.type == Event::Closed) app.close();
            if (mouseEvent.type == Event::MouseButtonPressed)
            {

                sf::Vector2i position = sf::Mouse::getPosition(app);
                dx = position.x / w;
                dy = position.y / w;
                std::cout << position.x << " " << position.y << " " << dx << " " << dy << "\n";
                Whites[i].setPosition(dx * w, dy * w);
                board1[dx][dy] = 1;
                ++i;
            }

        }

        app.draw(Whites[i]);
        app.draw(board);
        app.display();
    }
```

Comment: Можно использовать отдельный спрайт (sf::Sprite) для каждой фишки, либо (более низкий уровнь)  создать свой класс от sf::Drawable для отрисовки нескольких фишек по данным из массива.

Comment: Добавил код, можете подсказать что не так? Просто сейчас фишки даже не отрисовываются по нажатию.

Comment: Видимо это потому, что тут сначала отрисовывается одна фишка, а потом доска.

Comment: Да, разобрался, спасибо.